# node.js RegExp doesn't handle multiple matches with 'g' flag?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Does Javascript's RegExp#exec() NOT handle multiple results with the 'g' flag?  If not, what are the alternatives?

I have a string like this:

```
a*  2
b   3
c*  4
```

and I want to extract only those lines that have an asterisk.  I've written this regexp:

```
/\w+\*\s+(\d+)\n/g
```

(i.e. it matches a word followed by a literal asterisk followed by whitespace followed by a capturing group of digits followed by newline, and has the global flag turned on).

In the delightful https://regex101.com/#javascript, applying the string to the regexp returns two matches, as expected:

```
Match 1
1.   '2'
Match 2
1.   '4'
```

But in node.js, I get this:

```
> match = re.exec(str)
> match
[ 'a*  2\n', '2', index: 0, input: 'a*  2\nb   3\nc*  4\n' ]
```

It appears the match object is not multi-dimensional, or at least, it only captures the first match.

Am I missing something fundamental?  And (as I asked at the top) is there a sensible alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's RegExp#exec() does support multiple matches, but does not return them all at once. You need to call exec() multiple times. The docs for this functionality on MDN explains the issue and gives an example of how to use exec() for multiple matches.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Examples

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = 'abbcdefabh';
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[0] + '. ';
  msg += 'Next match starts at ' + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: Doh!  I depend on the MDN docs -- I don't know how I missed that one.  That's clearly the correct answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to preface this answer by saying that I know very little about Regex, *but*, I just performed my own testing and found that the issue could be with the `\n` in your regex.

Requiring the `\n` means that in a snippet like the one you posted, if there is no newline after `c* 4`, that line won't be matched.

`\w+\*\s+(\d+)` works just fine according to my tests on [Regexr](http://regexr.com/).

As I said, I may be off by a mile here, but that's just my thought.

**Edit**: The results of my testing:

```
/\w+\*\s+(\d+)\n/g

a*  2   [MATCH]
b   3
c*  4
```

And:

```
/\w+\*\s+(\d+)/g

a*  2   [MATCH]
b   3
c*  4   [MATCH]
```

Using the original, but putting a newline after `c`:

```
/\w+\*\s+(\d+)\n/g

a*  2   [MATCH]
b   3
c*  4   [MATCH]
\n
```

Comment: I appreciate your dedication to learning!  I didn't show the trailing \n on the last line, but it's there.  And note that I got the right results under regex101 (like regexr).  craigts gave the right answer.

Comment: @fearless_fool Ah well, I learned something new today then! ;)

Comment: It's a shame you got downvoted simply for posting what you learned.  But it's the the law of the StackOverflow jungle, and -- to be honest -- you didn't address the crux of the question: how do you process multiple matches using RegExp#match?  But do keep learning!

Comment: @fearless_fool Ah, doesn't bother me! :) It's all a learning experience. I'm always open-minded when it comes answering questions, as (at least in my history), oftentimes the question asked might be wrong entirely - I base my answers and problem solving skills around the code and expected output itself, rather than the programmer's preconceived idea of what may be wrong. In any case, it was still a useful experience!